# jQuery Get values of number fields depending on Button Click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 20 fields that are created (numbered 1-20) with corresponding submit buttons.  I need to retrieve the values of those fields for an AJAX post depending on which button number was clicked.  For example:

```
$(function(){
    $("#addCommentButton1").click(function(event) {



var trackid = $("#trackidField1").val();
var comment = $("#addcommentfield1").val();



$(function(){
    $("#addCommentButton2").click(function(event) {


var trackid = $("#trackidField2").val();
var comment = $("#addcommentfield2").val();
```

I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this than writing the function 20 times.

Thanks!

```
$(function(){
    $(".addCommentsExpBtn").click(function(event) {
        var container = $(this).closest(".songPost"); 
     container.find('.addCommentsExp').slideToggle();
});
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this,

```
<div>
      <input type="button" class="addCommentBtn" value="Add Comment">
      <input type="text" class='trackId'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="addCommentBtn" value="Add Comment">
      <input type="text" class='trackId'>
    </div>
```

and jquery,

```
$(function(){
   $(".addCommentBtn").click(function(event) {
             var parent=$(this).parent();      

            var trackid = $(".trackId",parent).val();
            //others
       });
});
```

Comment: I am a newbie. whats this code  $(".trackId",parent).val();  will do ? .

Comment: it will only select elements only within parent `div ` scope.http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context

Answer (score 0):

Give each of your elements a class name.

You can then write

```
$(function(){
    $(".addCommentButton1").click(function(event) {
        var container = $(this).closest(".commentBoxContainer");
        var trackid = container.find(".trackidField").val();
        var comment = container.find(".addcommentfield").val();
```

Comment: container.find("#trackidField1").val(); --------


Is this going to work for container.find("#trackidField2").val(); as well?  Or would I just delete the numbering from the fields?

Comment: Sorry; I meant to add a class.  All copies of each field should have the same non-numbered class.

Comment: I updated my code trying to test this out before I implement.  Can you see where this is going wrong?